# What is wrong with Drools rule?

Tags: java, jboss, drools, rule-engine, jboss-rules

I have a long time experience working with JBOSS Drools.
current project I'm working with uses Drools 4.

here is the one of the rules I have in project

```
rule "testcase"
   salience 300
    when
        $item : Item(itemTypeId in (Item.ITEM_TYPE_A, Item.ITEM_TYPE_B), targetId < 0)
        not Tegret(targetId == $item.targetId)
    then
        retract ($item);
end
```

idea is to retract such Items from working memory that does not have associated Target object.
I'm testing it with these objects in working memory:

Item {itemId=7305, itemTYpeId=ITEM_TYPE_A, targetId=-1023}
Target {targetId = -1023}

in this case rule should not fire, but it does.
after lot of experimenting I have found this strange behaviour:

rule "testcase2" fires, while "testcase1" does not.

```
rule "testcase1"
   salience 300
    when        
        $item : Item(itemTypeId in (Item.ITEM_TYPE_A, Item.ITEM_TYPE_B), targetId < 0)
        Tegret(targetId == $item.targetId)
    then
        ...
end

rule "testcase2"
   salience 300
    when        
        $item : Item(itemTypeId in (Item.ITEM_TYPE_A, Item.ITEM_TYPE_B), targetId < 0)
        Tegret($ti:targetId)
        eval($ti == $item.targetId)

    then
        ...
end
```

so what is going wrong here?
I'm running "testcase1" and "testcase2" separately on different program runs.

Comment: Have you tested the rules in a newer version of Drools? If so, did they work? i.e. Is this a Drools 4 bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after lots of experimenting and fiddling here is what I found:
I don't know if is it bug or not, but this was happening due to type differences between "linking" fields.

**Tagret.targetId** is int primitive.
**Item.targetId** is long primitive.

rewriting rule this way solved the problem:

```
rule "testcase"
   salience 300
    when
        $item : Item(itemTypeId in (Item.ITEM_TYPE_A, Item.ITEM_TYPE_B), targetId < 0)
        not Tegret(targetId == ((long)$item.targetId))
    then
        retract ($item);
end
```

re-read documentation to find any hints about field "compatibility" restriction. no result